# What can I use in place of the [AllowHtml] attribute in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I was using the `[AllowHtml]` attribute in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application, but now I'm trying to upgrade to MVC 5 and I get a compile error saying the attribute was not found. Was it removed? If so, what can I use in its place?

Comment: Have you tried [System.Web.Mvc.AllowHtml] ?

Comment: @the_lotus I did; I got the same error.

Comment: @mxmissile So the attribute is no longer used because HTML is always allowed in model properties? Isn't that a security concern?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) say it should work and I have a MVC 5 app that is working with it. Does your class have System.Web.Mvc.AllowHtml as reference? Are you adding it to a property (inside the model)?

Comment: Yes, it is being added to model properties. What do you mean by adding a reference to System.Web.Mvc.AllowHtml? It's a class; you don't add references to classes.

Comment: I mean, does the project that contains the class has a reference to System.Web.Mvc ?

Comment: Yes, the project does have a reference to `System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: @ekolis Sorry I retracted the flag after I noticed the mvc-5 tag. Just forgot to delete my comment. You are correct.